# Keycloak and large set of realm roles

Tags: keycloak

I have a large product that has at least 100 different roles that must be handled in the application.

There are number of (micro)services that are protected by Keycloak. Client (web-browser) uses bearer token to authenticate on this services.

If the user has many roles assigned, all of them are placed in token. This has significant performance impact on performed requests, especially when the token is passed between services in backend.

I know that i can use scopes to limit number of roles in token, but I would need to handle many access tokens in web-browser (Single page app). Am I right?

It is possible to use in some way Authorization API introduced in 2.x to handle this situation the better way? I tried to use policy enforcers, but they still are based on roles passed in the token.

It is possible that policy enforcer on service would check all assigned roles to the user, also those that are not passed by the access token?

Comment: Any solution to this issue?